# Transferring Wordpress site to local server (MAMP)

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, mamp

So, this is very new to me - I do not have a lot of coding experience! I have developed a Wordpress site but want the ability to work on it offline as I make changes and try new things.

I have  installed MAMP (Version 3.5) and copied my files over to the root directory via FTP. To test the transfer was successful, I tried to navigate to:

http://localhost:8888/PAS_wordpress (the folder name)

In response, Firefox (which is the most up-to-date version) responds with a  dialogue box:

> You have chosen to open:
>
> {BLANK}
>
> which is: application/x-httpd-php (418 bytes)
>   from http://localhost:8888
>
> What should firefox do with this file?

If I open the file I understand that it is php script (shown below), but I dont know why it isn't being processed. I have spent some time now trying to find answers. Some other people seem to have had similar problems, but not quite the same, or the solutions provided just dont work.

```
<?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

Can anyone help please? I am determined to get this to work! 
Many Thanks in advance...

Comment: You need to set up your database as well, and you need to search the database for live links (`http://www.yoursite.com`) to local links (`localhost/yourpage`) - or whatever is your link structure. [Lots of info on line](https://www.google.com/search?q=migrate+wordpress+to+localhost&oq=migrate+wordpress+to+local&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l4.6511j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=0&ie=UTF-8#q=migrate+wordpress+to+localhost&tbs=qdr:y)

Comment: Thanks. Have done this, and still have exactly the same problem. I dont understand why, but it appears that the server doesn't parse the php, but just serves it as a text file? I am not sure, and definitely don't know why! And ideas?

Comment: How did you fix it @IMills?

Answer (score 0):

In the local database, import an SQL dump file and then go into the WP_options table and you will see the first two rows will be a URL `http://example.com`
Change these to `http://localhost`

Comment: Thanks. Have done this, and still have exactly the same problem. I dont understand why, but it appears that the server doesn't parse the php, but just serves it as a text file? I am not sure, and definitely don't know why! And ideas?

Comment: Hey, other than that my only other advice is to look at what version of PHP your server is running